# Particle System: How to check distance between two points before arrival?

Tags: c++, distance, particles, particle-system

I am developing a simple time-based particle system.

One aspect I’m working on is an attractor. This works fine but I am having difficulty making the particle stop once it reaches the attractor. The reason is because although I am checking the distance from the particle to the attractor, it gets incremented every frame due to time and eventually goes past the 0.0. Let me post a code snippet to explain.

```
float dx = pattractorforcex - posx;
float dy = pattractorforcey - posy;
float dz = pattractorforcez - posz;
float distance = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy + dz * dz);

float force = dx / distance;
float force = dy / distance;
float force = dz / distance;
float force = time * pattractorforceint;
float posx2 = posx + force * forceX * drag; 
float posy2 = posy + force * forceY * drag;
float posz2 = posz + force * forceZ * drag;
float dx2 = pattractorforcex - posx2;
float dy2 = pattractorforcey - posy2;
float dz2 = pattractorforcez - posz2;
float distance2 - sqrt(dx2 * dx2 + dy2 * dy2 + dz2 * dz2);

if (distance2 > 0.05)
{
   posx = posx2;
   posy = posy2;
   posz = posz2;
}
else
{
   posx = pattractorforcex;
   posy = pattractorforcey;
   posz = pattractorforcez;
}
```

I realize this is **highly** inefficient code but that’s ok as I can optimize it once I understand what I’m doing wrong.

As you can see, I am calculating the distance from the attractor and the particle and then calculating a force from it to push / pull the particle with.

I have to perform a second distance check to get a true distance check. I realize this is highly inefficient.

Distance gets reduced every frame as it should and it eventually reaches 0.0 when the particle reaches the attractor. But then the next iteration, due to the time increase, starts increasing the distance and continues to push the particle beyond the attractor.

I suppose I need to somehow force *time* to stop once distance reaches 0.0 or perhaps there’s a better approach to this? If distance was positive and negative (which I know is impossible), I could perform the calculations only while it is greater than 0.0, for example, and easily constrain the movement.

Any help or suggestions?

Comment: Don't use `0.0` as the remove particle distance, use a value like `0.1`.  What value you chose will depend on the particle speed and the scale of your universe.

Comment: you can adjust the time such that the particle never travels say 90% of the remaining distance, then use an epsilon, such that the partice did reach its destination when the distance is <= epsilon

Comment: btw I am not sure if this is the best place to ask this question. Its more about simulations and physics ratehr than programming. There are ways to make your simulation stop that are completely fine concerning coding and c++, but might be poor for the simulation. Though I am not sure where the quesiton would be more ontopic

Answer (score 0):

Seeing more code would be beneficial to understand how your 'time' works in a sense: such as are you running a thread, a for loop, a while loop, etc.. Based on that you can try to implement `break` which stops loops to prevent any more things from happening (i.e. time or position changing)

example of how to use break:

```cpp
end = false;
do
{
    if (distance < 0.1)
        {
            break; //or end = true;
        }

}
while (!end)
```

Edit:
based on your comment then I think you want this:

**Instead of:**

```cpp
end = false;
do //main loop
{
    position = position - 1; //simple example of what you have
}
while (!end)
```

**Try using:**

```cpp
end = false;
do //main loop
{
    float position = 10.0 //example value
    if (position < 0.1)
    {
        position = 0.0
    }
    else
    {
        position = position - 1; //simple example of what you have
    }
}
while (!end)
```

**or try:**

```cpp
end = false;
bool can_move = true;
do //main loop
{
    if (can_move)
    {
        position = position - 1; //simple example of what you have
    }

}
while (!end)
```

Comment: Hi @Phoned_Leek25. Thanks for your suggestion. You are right, it’s tough without seeing the full code. I had tried breaking / continuing out of the loop but the problem with that is it affects all the other particles as well, including those that haven’t yet reached the attractor. Also, the aim is to make them stop, not make them disappear so I need to be able to constrain their movement despite the changing time factor.

Comment: instead of breaking then, have an if statement inside of your main loop, that checks for a boolean value before changing. if the value is true keep changing distance, once the value is false, safety if statement stops the value from changing.